# Change select columns from character to integers

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as such:

```
sample = data.frame(
  beer_brewerId = c("8481", "8481", "8481"),
  rev_app = c("4/5","1/5", "2/5"),
  beer_name = c("John Harvards Simcoe IPA", "John Harvards Simcoe IPA", "John Harvards American Brown Ale"),
  review_taste =c("6/10", "7/10", "6/10"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
str(sample)
```

I would like to convert only columns 2 and 4 from a character vector into an integer for analysis purposes. Normally, this would not be so difficult if all of the character columns I have I want to convert to  numeric with the following code, but this does not work as I want to keep column 3 as a chr type:

```
sample %>%
  select(2,4) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)
```

You can easily accomplish this with base r as:

```
#base approach
cols <- c("2","4")
data[cols] <- lapply(data[cols], as.numeric)
```

Is there an easy way to do this using dplyr, and even within a pipe sequence? If you were to select only certain columns using `select()`, it would not allow you to save the results back into the dataframe

Something like this would work, but as my dataset has 15+ columns, this seems like its very cumbersome code:

```
cleandf <- sample %>%
#Use transform or mutate to convert each column manually
transform(rev_app = as.integer(rev_app)) %>%
transform(review_taste = as.integer(review_taste))
```

Is `mutate_at`, or `mutate_each` meant to perform this task? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#Maybe something like this:
cols <- c("2","4")
data %>%
  mutate_each(is.character[cols], as.numeric)
```

Comment: "If you were to select only certain columns using select(), it would not allow you to save the results back into the dataframe" - you could use `add_columns(data)` ([sjmisc-pkg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjmisc)) to append the columns from data, and the selected columns will replace existing ones.

Comment: The values in those two columns will all become NA when coerced to numeric.  They don't automagically get evaluated.  Be aware of that.

Comment: You need to replace the /5 and /10 first. Once you do that, you can coerce it to a numeric properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to accomplish this is through using mutate_at with the specified column indexes:

```
sample <- sample %>%
  #Do normal mutations on the data
  mutate(rev_app =  str_replace_all(rev_app, "/5", "")) %>%      
  mutate(review_taste =  str_replace_all(review_taste, "/10", "")) %>%

  #Now add this one-liner onto your chain
  mutate_at(c(2,4), as.numeric) %>%
  glimpse(., n=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the `mutate_at` function.

```
sample = data.frame(beer_brewerId = c("8481", "8481", "8481"),
     rev_app = c("4/5","1/5", "2/5"),
     beer_name = c("John Harvards Simcoe IPA", "John Harvards Simcoe IPA", "John Harvards American Brown Ale"),
     review_taste =c("6/10", "7/10", "6/10"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# get rid of "/"
clean <- function(foo) {
         sapply(foo, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
         }
# you can replace c(2,4) by whatever columns you need
clean_sample <- sample %>% 
                mutate_at(c(2,4), clean)
```

Columns 2 and 4 are now numeric.

Comment: I think the two columns are only in his sample data, his original data frame has more columns that need modifications, if I understood right.

Comment: @Daniel you're right, I just realized that and updated my answer :) Thanks!

Comment: That is definitely helpful, as I was ended up using mutate_at. Do you find yourself using purr to solve problems like this, or using dplyr instead?

Comment: I use more and more purrr functions, most of the time together with dplyr and tidyr.

Comment: So you don't use the purr-like functions in dplyr? I'm a huge fan of dplyr, but at times I'm not sure purrr is worthwhile when you have mutate_, summarize_, etc..

Comment: I try to only add packages as I need them. I found an easier solution for your problem, see edited answer above. No need to mutate to numeric because `eval` already returns a numeric output.